# getting Meilisearch disjunctive facet searches to work like in the GIF examples in the Meilisearch documentation

Tags: meilisearch

I am using Meilisearch with Laravel. The functionalities of Scout seem limited, so I call the Meilisearch instance directly, and try to use the facet search.

SUMMARY OF QUESTION:

Meilisearch Faceted Filtering seems to return a facet distribution that supposes conjunctive searches, even when the request filter specifies a disjunctive search.

DETAILS:

What I try to achieve is what is shown in the GIF for Meilisearch documentation: https://www.meilisearch.com/docs/learn/advanced/faceted_search#disjunctive-facets

When the user selects "Fiction" and "Literature" in the "Genre" facet, the search returns all Fiction OR Literature (disjunctive search), which is what I want. Then, the user can still choose to add another option to the selection (for instance Classics), to add the "Classics" documents to the hits.

My problem is that when my user has selected "Fiction" and "Literature", the other Genre options disappear probably because there is no "Classic" book in the "Fiction" and "Literature" hits. So my user cannot add a third option, which is what disjunctive searches should allow...

It is even more obvious with the Language facet in https://www.meilisearch.com/docs/learn/advanced/faceted_search#conjunctive-facets: when "English" is selected, the "French" checkbox is still available. Although in that case it shows zero French books found because that search is conjunctive and the books are either French or English.

How does Meilisearch achieve this decorrelation between the Hits, and the Distributions ?

My PHP code is the following (deals with products):

```
        $this->options = array(
            'filter' => $filters,
            'facets' => ['STYLE', 'MARQUE', 'COULEUR'],
            'attributesToRetrieve' => $displayedAttributes
        );

        /** @return array (hits, distribution, stats)
        $facets = $this->index->search( $search_string, $this->options );
        $this->meili_hits = $facets->getHits();
        $this->meili_dist = $facets->getFacetDistribution();
        $this->meili_stats = $facets->getFacetStats();
```

$filters is a query built from the html form's checkboxes statuses, conjunctive between facets and disjunctive within, for instance:

```
$filters = [["STYLE='baroque'", "STYLE:'modern'"],["COLOUR='black', COLOUR='white'"];
```

Which is equivalent (according to the doc) to "(baroque OR modern) AND (black OR white)".
My criteria are exclusive (products are either black, white or yellow), so the $facets->getFacetDistribution() does not return any additional COLOUR facets (i.e. checkboxes in the ui that would allow my user to add yellow & green products to the search).

In fact, my user does not even get a chance to issue this search request: as soon as he clicks the 'baroque' checkbox, the form is submitted, the checkbox menu is updated with the new Facet Distribution and all the other STYLE checkboxes disappear. Because there is no product that is baroque and has also another style. So my user is stuck with the baroque "only" search results.

@Meilisearch: would be great if you could share the code that is behind your examples !

E.

Comment: Seems that the beginning of the answer would be here: https://github.com/meilisearch/product/discussions/187. If anyone has an example of using the multi-search for this purpose, would be great !

Answer (score 0):

Meilisearch is using the [multi-search route](https://www.meilisearch.com/docs/reference/api/multi_search) to achieve this behavior through [instant-meilisearch](https://github.com/meilisearch/instant-meilisearch), using the `refinementList` widget with the `or` operator and using the `keepZeroFacets` too in the [options object parameter](https://github.com/meilisearch/instant-meilisearch#-customization) of the `instantMeilisearch` function

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it. 

For the moment, I have found a way to do it with multisearch.
I have 3 facets (style, colour, brand). So I do a multisearch with 4 searches:
The first to get the hits corresponding to the filter (styles AND colours AND brands, with OR within each facet), then 3 queries, one for each facet.

Each facet specific query returns the distribution for the other 2 filters. Like the Color query returns the distribution after applying the Style & Brand filters. Then I reassemble the 3 distributions to create the checkbox menu.

It "sort of works"...

Comment: @Eric I’m currently working on a project with Laravel and Meilisearch and ‘solved’ it the same way. I think this is just the way it works.

Comment: Excellent. Glad to see I am not alone!

Indeed, CaroFG’s answer is probably the cleanest solution, but it involves instant-mellisearch and it is therefore a front-end solution, using javascript packages. At this stage I am trying to do it with HTML forms and PHP in the backend (for SEO reasons) hence my choice.

Eric